# How to get the most recent n records per group and aggregate them into an array

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I know that this is a common problem, and I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680464/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results-with-bigquery-standard-sql) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63340082/get-n-most-recent-records-in-each-category-postgres) but neither of these solutions are working for me.

I have a table with fields `session_time`, `user` and `email` (these fields are just dummy placeholders, my real schema is different so please don't look too much into their names)
supposing each `user` can have various `emails` related to it, I need to output, per row:

1 - a `user`

2 - an array consisting of every `email` related to the `user`

However, some users have WAY too many emails, so I need to limit them to the most recent entries, lets say 2 most recent per user.

```
WITH
  sample_data AS (
  SELECT
    '2023-06-12 10:00:00' AS session_time,
    '1' AS user,
    'example@example.com' AS email
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    '2023-06-12 11:00:00' AS session_time,
    '2' AS user,
    'example@example.com' AS email
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    '2023-06-12 12:00:00' AS session_time,
    '3' AS user,
        'example@example.com' AS email,
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
  '2023-06-12 13:00:00' AS session_time,
  '3' AS user,
  'example2@example.com' AS email
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
  '2023-06-12 14:00:00' AS session_time,
  '3' AS user,
  'example3@example.com' AS email
)

, filtered_user_email AS (
SELECT
  user,
  email,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user, email ORDER BY MAX(session_time) DESC) row_num
FROM
  sample_data
GROUP BY
  uuid,
  user
)
```

running `SELECT user, array_agg(distinct email) as emails FROM filtered_user_email WHERE row_num <= 2 group by user` outputs every row, because every row gets a row_num of 1, so for user 3, I get 3 entries instead of just the two most recent ones.

How can I then just select the 2 most recent emails per user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you just need to change the `partition` of your `row_number`:

```
select usr, array_agg(email) emails
from (
    select usr, email, 
        row_number() over(partition by usr order by max(session_time))rn
    from sample_data s
    group by usr, email
) t
where rn <= 2
group by usr
```